# Removing simplices from a simplicial complex in sage

Tags: simplicial-complex, sagemath

The context for this problem is this: given a simplicial complex $X$ and a simplex $\sigma \subseteq X$, I want to define a new simplicial complex $Y_\sigma$ to be the subcomplex of $X$ with vertex set $V(X)-V(\sigma)$. Eventually I want to loop over all such $\sigma$, so I would need some way of keeping this fairly general and automated.

My thought was the following:

1. Extract the vertex set from $X$.
2. Use the `.faces()` function gives me a list of all faces
3. For any prescribed face $\sigma$ in that list, extract the vertex set $V(\sigma)$
4. Use `.generated_subcomplex()` on the difference $V(X) - V(\sigma)$ to obtain $Y_\sigma$.

Steps 1 and 3 are giving me grief, however. The [documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/topology/sage/topology/simplicial_complex.html) doesn't seem to have any way to get vertices from a simplicial complex. I'm also not sure I understand what the face is as an object; I would have expected sage to also treat it as a simplex/simplicial complex, but I'm not sure if that's actually the case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a math question and probably belongs instead on [ask.sagemath.org](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/). But I find that I've written an answer, so here it is:

I would recommend using the `remove_faces` method. If you have a simplex `sigma` in `X`, you can do

```
X.remove_faces([[a] for a in sigma])
```

Explanation: suppose `sigma` is the simplex `[0,1,3]`. Then `[[a] for a in sigma]` returns `[[0], [1], [3]`: a list of lists, each one being a single number — a $0$-simplex. If you want to be mathematically correct about it, you could do instead `[Simplex([a]) for a in sigma]` so that this is actually a list of simplices, not just a list of lists, but Sage lets you be sloppy and treat a list of numbers (like `[1]`) as a simplex.

Passing this list to `X.remove_faces(...)` then removes those faces and any other simplices forced by this: if you remove the $0$-simplex `[0]`, then you have to remove all simplices containing it.

Warning: `X.remove_faces(...)` modifies `X`. You might instead want to make a copy of `X` and modify that:

```
Y = SimplicialComplex(X)
Y.remove_faces(...)
```

should modify `Y` but leave `X` unchanged. If you want to be really careful:

```
X.set_immutable()  # makes X unchangeable
Y = SimplicialComplex(X, is_mutable=True)  # explicitly make Y changeable, just in case
Y.remove_faces(...)
```

By the way: `X.vertices()` will return the list of [vertices](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/topology/sage/topology/simplicial_complex.html#sage.topology.simplicial_complex.SimplicialComplex.vertices) of `X`, in response to your statement near the bottom of your question. If you want to know what sort of thing a face is:

```
sage: T = simplicial_complexes.Torus()
sage: e = T.n_cells(1)[3] # some edge of T
sage: e
(2, 6)
sage: type(e)
<class 'sage.topology.simplicial_complex.Simplex'>
```

so a simplex in a simplicial complex is a [Simplex](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/topology/sage/topology/simplicial_complex.html#sage.topology.simplicial_complex.Simplex).

Comment: Oh thanks; I knew SE had its own tag for sagemath, but didn't realize that there was a forum dedicated to sage. Thanks so for very thoroughly answering my question despite this fact.